# I am having issues with installing Chameleon and jinja2 with python3

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, chameleon, python-3.2

I have decided to use python 3 in a project. When I tried easy_install pyramid, one of the things that came with pyramid (namely Chameleon) threw a syntax error.

I decided to use Pyramid_Jinja2 instead and tried easy_install Jinja2 and I got a few more syntax errors.

Has anyone noticed these problems. Chameleon templates render well but I am not even able to get jinja2 to work at all. I tried `pcreate -s pyramid_jinja2_starter MyProject` the error says scaffold does not exist.

Was python3.2 a bad idea?

I have been on google the whole day. I can not even find a decent tutorial that tells me what to do when I am using python3.2 with pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid and Chameleon and Jinja2 all support python 3 (see the [Python 3 porting page](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/wiki/Python-3-Porting) on the Pyramid project wiki); your problem resides with `easy_install` instead, I think.

Install either [distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/) or [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/), which both work properly on Python 3.

If you still encounter errors when easy_installing packages, post those as *new* questions here on SO to see if we can help you.

Do note that many instrumental packages you may need for your web application may not yet have been ported to python 3 (or have python 3 counterparts), and thus it *may* be a good idea to stay on python 2.7 for a little while yet.

Comment: Thanks man. I had given up hope. We have currently decided use python 2.7, but code using python 3 style as much as possible. we will migrate to 3 whenever it is ready.